# How can you get the file extension into a calculated field on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to calculate the file extension in a calculated field in SharePoint, so I'm trying something like this (which doesn't work):

```
last(split(body('Get_file_properties')?['{name}'],'.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculated column does not support the function you used above.

In SharePoint Online, as a workaround, we could create a single line of text, format the text as shown below:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$File_x0020_Type]"
}
```

Result:

[image]

**-------------------------------------Update-------------------------------**

If you want to use this in flow, please check as following:

```
last(split(body('Get_file_properties')?['{FileNameWithExtension}'],'.'))
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Can you use this output in power automate?

Comment: Yes, you could use this newly created column in power automate.Or you could filter file based on extension directly in flow, please refer to:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Sharepoint-filter-by-file-type-extension/td-p/192353

Comment: Thanks,
I tried it and it works on the screen, only the value isn't actually stored in the record. So if I create a flow and get the file properties, then the value is empty.
If I create a calculated field which shoes the value of the few File extention field, then that's also empty.

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.
THat's how I'm doing it indeed, but I'm trying to do as little as possible with flow because that's hard to deploy on new sites